# color in beamer theme

Tags: beamer, color

[image]

I want to create a representation like this, I use Hannover theme but I can't find the color

Answer (score 2):

The presentation you show in your image most likely uses a background image for the sidebar. If you just want a similar colour, you can change the sidebar colour and the colour of most structural elements like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{39,75,133}
\usecolortheme[named=myblue]{structure}
\usetheme{Hannover}
\setbeamercolor{sidebar}{bg=myblue}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Plan}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{section name}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{title}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]